# I get $10$ units per day, plus $10$ more each consecutive day. (Day 1, $10$; Day 2, $20$; Day 3, $30$; etc). When will I have gotten $4,800,000$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have this game that I get $10$ (let's call them units) a day, and everyday I sign in consecutively I get $10$ more. So Day 1, I get $10$; Day 2, $20$; Day 3, $30$; and so on. The ultimate goal is $4,800,000$.

I did some math that I'm not sure is correct as I've never really done any math like this before. I tried $1$ and $2$ years but didn't think that many consecutive days would be enough, so I did $3$ years. This is my math.

1. There are 365 days a year x 3 would be 1,095 days.
2. I multiplied this number by 10 because on the 1,095th day i would be getting this much on that specific day so 10 x 1095 = 10,950.
3. Then i added all the counternumbers for each day which would just be 10,960 because 10,950 +10 = 10,960, 10,940 to 20 = 10,960 ect.
4. I then multiplied the counternumbers (or whatever the real term for that is) by the number of days which was 1,095 to get 12,001,200. So 10,960 × 1,095 = 12,001,200.
5. Since only half of those amount of days are really used though since i added the counternumbers i have to divide by two. So 12,001,200 ÷ 2 = 6,000,600.

I know this would mean it would be less than three years and i overshot by 1.2 million but i was just trying to get an estimate of how long it might take if i were to try to login everday and do it the free to play way.

Comment: $1+2+3+\dots+n=\frac12 n(n+1)$.

Comment: Look for "arithmetic sequence" in a highschool math text.

Comment: Please don't take this as a criticism, as it is meant to help.  But there is an extremely well-known result (listed by @TedShifrin, above) that makes this problem very simple indeed.  If you haven't studied such basic math, well, you end up flailing around with dead ends, testing candidate values of $n$ (first higher, then lower, ...).  All this shows that just a little knowledge goes a very VERY long way.

Answer (score 2):

It's great that you're experimenting with math like this!

I'm not 100% following your steps(I don't fully understand what counternumbers are in your sense, but I think your method is about the same as mine), but I'll try to explain how I would go about solving this.

What we want to do is find some value $x$ such that $10+20+30+40+\cdots+10x$, such that that the total sum is equal to $4,800,000$($x$ is many days it will take you to reach your goal). Dealing with math involving things like $\cdots$ is a bit tricky, but most of the things you do with normal expressions(such as $2+5+7$) still apply. In particular, we can factor out a $10$ from the sum to get $10(1+2+3+4+\cdots+x)$. This is how I'll leave this for now.

So, we want to find $1+2+3+4+\cdots+x$. It is known that this is $\frac{x(x+1)}{2}$, and I'll show you how to derive it.

Let $1+2+3+4+\cdots+x=S$. We know that $1+2+3+4+ \cdots + x=x+ \cdots + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1$. If we add these two expressions together, we will get $2S$. However, adding them together in a certain way can reveal something nice.

Adding them gives us $1+2+3+\cdots+(x-2)+(x-1)+x+x+(x-1)+(x-2)+\cdots+3+2+1=2S$. At first, this doesn't look much better, but distributing the terms differently will reveal a nice trick. We move the second $x$ in front of the first $1$, the second $x-1$ in front of the first $2$, and so on. This will give us

$1+x+2+(x-1)+3+(x-2)+ \cdots + (x-1) + 2 + x + 1 = 2S$

And the trick is revealed. We can combine these terms to get a super nice expression! We just get

$(x+1)+(x+1)+(x+1) + \cdots + (x+1) + (x+1) = 2S$

Now, because there are $x$ terms, we have

$x (x+1) = 2S$

and

$\boxed{S = \frac{x(x+1)}{2}}$

I think this technique is similar to what you are doing with the counternumbers, but I am not 100% sure. Anyway, leading back to our problem, the number of units you get after $x$ days is $10 \cdot \frac{x(x+1)}{2} = 5 x(x+1)$, and we want to set this equal to $4,800,000$. This gives us

$5x (x+1) = 4,800,000$

$x (x+1) = 960,000$

$x^2 + x = 960,000$

$x^2 + x - 960,000 = 0$

I am not sure if you have learned techniques to evaluate quadratics like this, but if you haven't, plugging this into a calculator(such as Wolfram Alpha) will give you $x \approx 979.3$ and $x \approx -980.3$ as answers. Clearly, we want the positive solution, so it will take you $\boxed{980}$ days to reach 4,800,000 units(after $979$ days you will have a bit less than 4,800,000 units and after $980$ days you will have a bit more than 4,800,000 units).

I hope this helps, and if you have any more questions let me know! If you're looking for a deeper introduction to this type of math, I'd recommend asking your math teacher at school next year[I assume you're still at school and it's summer now].

Sidenote: If your counternumber technique is the same as what I'm doing, then I don't think there's an official term for it, but counternumber is absolutely a great word for it. Definitely shows that you at least understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You did everything correctly. If you want to compute the exact number of days you need, you can use the formula Ted Shifrin pointed out in the comments: After $n$ days you got
$$10+20+30+...+10\cdot n=10\cdot(1+2+3+...+n)=\frac{10}{2}n(n+1)=5n(n+1)$$
units. So you can set this equal to $4,800,000$ and solve for $n$:
$$5n(n+1)=4800000$$
$$n(n+1)=960000$$
$$n^2+n-960000=0.$$
Now, this equation has two solutions, but we are only interested in the positive one:
$$n=-\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac 14+960000}\approx 979.3.$$
So, this means you will need at least $980$ days.